# Python LXML: Modify CDATA

Tags: python, lxml, cdata, lxml.objectify

When I'm manipulating XML parsed with the Python LXML module (specifically `lxml.objectify`, but I don't think it makes a difference), how can I preserve CDATA?

Given the following results:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify, etree
>>> xml = '''
  <Root>
   <Child>
    <![CDATA[abcd]]>
   </Child>
  </Root>
  '''
>>> parser = objectify.makeparser(strip_cdata=False)
>>> parsed = objectify.XML(xml, parser=parser)
>>> etree.tostring(parsed)
'<Root><Child><![CDATA[abcd]]></Child></Root>'
>>> type(parsed.Child)
<type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>
>>> parsed.Child.text
'abcd'
>>> parsed.Child = 'efgh'
>>> etree.tostring(parsed)
'<Root><Child xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" py:pytype="str">efgh</Child></Root>'
```

I'd like that last line to still have the `<![CDATA[....]>`.  But I can't see any way of either preserving it or recreating it.  Attempts to access the content of the `<Child>` element produce a bare string, and modifying the content of that element magically disappears the CDATA section.

What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: note that `<![CDATA[x]]>` and `x` are the same if they don't contain xml-specific characters.  Why do you need it to say CDATA?

Comment: Because it feeds legacy software that cats about the difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
>>> parsed = etree.XML('''
...   <Root>
...    <Child>
...     <![CDATA[abcd]]>
...    </Child>
...   </Root>
... ''', parser)
>>> print etree.tostring(parsed)
<Root>
   <Child>
    <![CDATA[abcd]]>
   </Child>
  </Root>
>>> parsed.getchildren()[0].text = etree.CDATA('efgh updated')
>>> etree.tostring(parsed)
'<Root>\n   <Child><![CDATA[efgh updated]]></Child>\n  </Root>'
>>>
```

Comment: No good - this produces `'<Root><Child>&lt;lxml.etree.CDATA object at 0x7f3ab54a9e70&gt;</Child></Root>'`.

Comment: it could be a thing with the objectify library. I've updated the answer using just the parser.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've ended up doing.